# Applying Gaussian blur kernel

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I am working with a Gaussian blur I wrote, and I am currently unable to come up with a way to check and then apply correctly the matrix on the borders. I have already done a loop to apply it to the pixels that are far enough away from the borders of the image. I don't see how to do an algorithm that can get the coordinates of a pixel, calculate if any row or column (or both) of the kernel ends up outside the boundaries of the image, and clone the pixels in the opposite row or column, or just apply the matrix to the pixels around the target. I had thought of using if-else statements, but I immediately saw it probably wouldn't work.

I am not asking for code, I just want some help with getting the logic right, so I can implement it in my program. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such problem may be solved by expanding an image to required size and then applying the kernel to ROI. For example, to apply 5*5 kernel to 100*100 image, you can expand the image to 102*102 size by duplicating an edge pixels, and then apply the kernel to the 100*100 ROI in the center.

Comment: ROI? Also, how would you expand the image by duplicating pixels without having gaps in the corners?

Comment: ROI is region of interest, if this is your question. Of course, image expanding cannot be done in-place, you need to allocate another image with greater size. In my example, filter must be applied starting from the pixel [2, 2] of expanded image. This is the way used for an image convolution in IPP (Inter Performance Primitives).

Comment: This is illustration of such approach: http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/441878 http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ippi/ippi_ch4/functn_CopyReplicateBorder.html

Comment: I can see what you mean, but for me it would be more trouble than it's worth, as I would need a way to scale the image...

Comment: No scaling is required. Well, this is one of possible ways to solve this problem, which is widely used in image processing.